# How to clear badge in TabView on SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, null, badge

Showing a badge is easy enough using the `.badge(content)` modifier, but to remove it the `.badge(nil)` modifier doesn't work despite being, apparently, an option in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/badge(_:)-84e43).

```
TabView {
    VStack {
        Text("Tab 1")
    }
    .tabItem {
        Text("Tab 1")
    }
    .badge(1) // works as expected
    
    VStack {
        Text("Tab 2")
    }
    .tabItem {
        Text("Tab 2")
    }
    .badge(nil) // doesn't work

    VStack {
        Text("Tab 3")
    }
    .tabItem {
        Text("Tab 3")
    }
    .badge(elementsCount > 0 ? elementsCount : nil) // What I wan't to actually do, which of course also doesn't work
}
```

What is it I am not getting? Or the only option to display a badge using a condition is to create an entirely different view path with an alternate but identical tabitem except with no badge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The badge is shown when it's not zero. So, the following works:

```
TabView {
    VStack {
        Text("Tab 1")
    }
    .tabItem {
        Text("Tab 1")
    }
    .badge(1) // works as expected
    
    VStack {
        Text("Tab 2")
    }
    .tabItem {
        Text("Tab 2")
    }
    .badge(0) // badge not shown

    VStack {
        Text("Tab 3")
    }
    .tabItem {
        Text("Tab 3")
    }
    .badge(elementsCount) // When zero, the badge is not shown
}
```